# Oracle Deriving MD5 incorrectly when DateTime Concatenated with Text

Tags: sql, oracle, md5

Please consider this SQL on Oracle 12c

```
select to_date('01-02-2020','MM-DD-YYYY'),
standard_hash (to_date('01-02-2020','MM-DD-YYYY'), 'MD5') Only_Date_MD5,
to_date('01-02-2020 12:34:56','MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),
standard_hash (to_date('01-02-2020 12:34:56','MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS'), 'MD5') DateTime_MD5,
standard_hash (to_date('01-02-2020','MM-DD-YYYY') || 'SomeText', 'MD5') Date_Concat_Text_MD5,
standard_hash (to_date('01-02-2020 12:34:56','MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS') || 'SomeText', 'MD5') DateTime_Concat_Text_MD5
from dual;
```

Output

```
SOME_DATE                   01/02/2020
ONLY_SOME_DATE_MD5          6D44D021F4D2CACA3DBEC6E88AEEB7AD
SOME_DATETIME               01/02/2020 12:34:56
SOME_DATETIME_MD5           F8FDBBC5181E79B99A1EE13CB71A1D46
DATE_CONCAT_TEXT_MD5        **FE7DA8E96A7233A33F03CC592A929011**
DATETIME_CONCAT_TEXT_MD5    **FE7DA8E96A7233A33F03CC592A929011**
```

Why is Oracle MD5 returning same value for a Date concatenated with text and DateTime(with same Date) concatenated with same text. It is discarding the time portion of DateTime while deriving the MD5.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `standard_hash()`.  The issue is the implicit conversion of a `date` to a string.

When you convert a `date` *implicitly* to a string (or using `to_char()` with no format), then the result is only the date portion.  So this:

```
select to_date('01-02-2020 12:34:56', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS') || 'abc'
from dual
```

returns:

```
02-JAN-20abc
```

For your purposes, I would strongly recommend using `to_char()` to convert back to a more detailed representation.  You could also use `to_timestamp()` instead -- the default representation would include the time.

So:

```
select to_timestamp('01-02-2020 12:34:56', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS') || 'abc'
from dual
```

returns:

```
02-JAN-20 12.34.56.000000000abc
```

Comment: Using `to_char` with an explicit format is **fine**, but using `to_timestamp` only shifts **the problem** as the result  remains dependent from the `NLS` session setting. So I would **not recommend** it. Run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF';` and repeat the query to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice (or may be a *workaround*) to *calculate a hash code* of concatenated columns with a different data type (which leads inevitable to a data type conversion) is to set explicitly before this step the NLS settings to the most covering options.

Example

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR';
```

This will **1) not *eat up* some parts of the data** in the conversion and **2) will produce a deterministic result** independent of the session setting.

You may need to store the previous values are recover them after the concatenation.

This step will ensure an expected result of your sample data.

The *other thing* you shoud consider is to use a **special concatenation delimiter** (a string that *doesn't appear in the data*)

Example

```
 col1||chr(10)||col1
```

This will ensure that the two rows with `col1 NULL, col2 'A'`  and `col1 'A', col2 NULL` will produce a *different* hash code after the concatenation.